# mongodb query using several conditions in php

Tags: mongodb

sql query like this:

```
if($this->config['features']['email_login'] === true) $query ="SELECT ID,  PASSWORD FROM user WHERE username =? OR email=?  ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1";}
```

i didn't know properly this mongo query..but i can try many way ..if any one know can write this query in php ..i can told this query in sql above can converted it to monogodb with php.
i can execute this query in mongodb but using php not working

```
db.people.find(
    { $or: [ { status: "A" } ,
             { age: 50 } ] },
{ user_id: 1, status: 1, _id: 0 }
)
```

i can try in php this way

```
$db->find(array(
    'ID' => $Id,
    '$or'=> array(
        array('username'=>'smart' ),
        array('email' => 'smart@gmail.com')),
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to get on record from database so you don't have to use `find()` and `sort`, you can try the `findOne()` function

```
$db->findOne(array(
        'ID' => $Id,
        '$or' => array(
            array('username' => 'smart'),
            array('email' => 'smart@gmail.com')),
    ));
```

Comment: no i can try to get id and password ..if you see above i can explain in sql query ..i just try select id, password from user where username OR email ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1..this my query

Answer (score 0):

The query is pretty easy. In your particular case i would use following query:

```
db.myCollection.find({username:"theUsername", email:"theEmail"}, {id:1, password:1}).sort({id:1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: you can given this answer in server side but i need in php query

Comment: now i can change and  explain my doubt in clearly in above

Comment: I don't know the php driver for mongodb. Is there no way to execute full find() query?